# Placing a graph in a specific place

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a button that activates a macro that creates a graph from a table.

When I press the button, it places the graph on the data.

How can I place the graph on K475?

```vb
Sub makeagraph()
'
' makeagraph îà÷øå
' makes a new graph for the table
'
' ÷éöåø î÷ùéí: Ctrl+g
'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
    Range("H473:I478").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("k$473:$I$478")
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 253
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub CreateChartPositioning()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData SOURCE:=Range("k$473:$I$478")
   ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
   ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 253
   With Range("K475")
        ActiveChart.Parent.top = .top
        ActiveChart.Parent.left = .left
   End With
   Debug.Print ActiveChart.Parent.TopLeftCell.Address 'only to prove its position (in Immediate Window)
End Sub
```

Your code must set where the created chart to be placed. `TopLeftCell` is a `ReadOnly` property...

Comment: its still not good it puts the graph on XDS positon

Comment: @liri_ roz This cannot be possible... What does the last code line return in `Immediate Window`? `Ctrl + G` being in VBE to see it...

Comment: not sure i understand the comment but its still not working it placed it on very far cell

Comment: @liri_ roz Are there hidden rows and row 475 is one of them? Do you understand what `Debug.Print "something"` does? It sends a string in `Immediate Window`. `Imediate Window` can be seen if you press `Ctrl + K` when being in Visual Basic for Applications Editor (**VBE**). Last line of the above code should show in `Immediate Window` the top left cell address of the chart in discussion. What address does it show? If not confidential, can you share the workbook you are trying the code on?

Comment: @liri_ roz Is it still anything unclear?

Comment: Thanks anyway!! i will try again

Comment: @liri_ roz Besides trying, can you answer my clarification questions? If you do not understand something, please ask for clarifications! No be ashamed, even for simple things. We are here to help...